# Does Java change the value of only the modified fields from cache?

Tags: java, caching, cpu, cpu-cache

According to my understanding, when a write-back happens from the cache to the main memory, it will write the entire cache block. This might include bytes/words which were not modified as well, as the dirty bit is set on a cache block as a whole.

In this, I am assuming that CPU architectures generally don't track 'dirtiness' on a byte-level. Feel free to correct my assumption if **all** the present architectures do track on a byte-level.

Say, two java fields, say `a` and `b` reside side by side and have the same tag. So, while caching, they would be placed in the same cache block.

Say there's a thread running in a core which updates only the value of `a`, but not `b`. Then, would actually the value of both `a` and `b` be updated in the main memory from the cache?
Or does java have something to ensure that only the value of `a` is updated, given that only `a` is changed?

Does java even have a role here? Or is it all dependent on the CPU architecture?

**My exact concern**

Assume initially, `a=1`, `b=1`
Say we have two threads T1 and T2. T1 does only one thing, it sets `a=2`. Similarly, T2 does `b=2`.

Assume we have a multi-core environment with cores C1 and C2 running T1 and T2 respectively. Both cache the values `a=1, b=1`.

Say T1 finishes first. Cache of C1 is written back.
So, now, in the main memory, `a=2, b=1`.
Now, T2 finishes. Now when cache is written back, does it set `a=1, b=2` because C2 had `a=1` in its cache?

Or does Java have any guarantee against this?

Assume that no Happens Before/After relationship is established. No synchronization or volatile or anything else of that sort.

Feel free to correct any of my assumptions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nitpicking: Writes in theory don't need to go to main memory; they could stay in the cache indefinitely depending on the cache coherence algorithm used.

The problem you are referring to, is called word tearing and the JVM should protect against it.

Check out the following links:

- https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-17.html#jls-17.6
- https://shipilev.net/blog/2014/jmm-pragmatics/#_part_ii_word_tearing

I'm not familiar with other architectures, but on the X86 loads and stores can be done at the byte level. An n-byte field, will always be n-byte aligned; so it will never be split over 2 cache-lines. And since a boolean in Java, is stored in a byte, word tearing can't happen on the X86.

Comment: When you say that the writes need not go to the main memory, you mean like what happens in write-back, meaning the deferred writing, waiting for when that particular cache block needs to be evicted, or is invalidated?

Comment: If we look at Java, when a thread has finished execution, then cache-write must happen, right? Or are there no guarantees?

Comment: Invalidation doesn't mean that the cache line needs to be written to main memory. Assuming MESI in the next example. CPU1 has read a cache-line (so it is in SHARED state), and CPU2 wants to write to the same cache-line. The writing core will do a RFO (Request For Ownership) which will invalidate the cache-line at CPU1 and expose it as EXCLUSIVE/MODIFIED to CPU2. But the cache-line doesn't need to be written to main memory since it is not dirty.

Comment: Writing changes to memory is a fallacy. It is up to the cache coherence algorithm when a write to main memory is needed. Writing to main memory is an artifact of the cache coherence algorithm and limitation on the amount of resources. Caches are the source of truth.

Comment: Small addition to the above example. If CPU1 has read a cache-line, and no other core has, then the cache-line will be in EXCLUSIVE state; not shared. Only when there is another CPU that also has read the same cache-line, it will be in SHARED state.

Comment: Right... Sorry, the dirty bit flew out of my mind for a 'bit' (sorry :P) there... So you are saying that even if there has been some changes... the system might simply opt to "coordinate" among the caches, rather than write back to the main memory?

Comment: According to my admittedly limited knowledge, each core in some architectures has one or more private lower caches (at least L1 is private) and the upper ones might be shared. So, the co-ordination question applies only to the private caches, I suppose.

Comment: "the system might simply opt to "coordinate" among the caches, rather than write back to the main memory?" Correct. Writing to main memory eats from the bandwidth and is slow; best to leave it in the cache where possible.

Comment: Systems that use MESI for example need to write the cacheline back to main memory if the cacheline is modified and a different CPU wants to read it. But an improvement of MESI is MOESI, whereby a dirty cacheline can be shared (it is put in OWNED state), without needing to write it to main memory. So writing to main memory is just an artifact of the algorithm and the amount of resources available.

Comment: Got it... Thanks for all your help and the links as well... They have been very helpful and addressed the exact problem I was worried about :)